# Ribbon CommandAction : Parameter value shows "undefined"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-actions

XML Code

```
<CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_NewRActionButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}&amp;SPSource={Source}"/>
```

App.js code:

```
var sourceUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter(url, "SPSource"));
```

I am getting undefined value for (parameter)sourceurl.

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved by using below code :

```
sourceUrl1 = getQueryStringParameter2("SPSource");

sourceurl2 = decodeURIComponent(sourceUrl1);
```

also find the function for getQueryStringParameter :
where

```
function getQueryStringParameter2(paramToRetrieve, url) {
    if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        var params = url.split("?")[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }

}
```